# Why does xcopy exit with code 9009 in Visual Studio post-build step?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xcopy

I am getting the following error, which I don't understand. Any suggestions?

> Error 1 The command "xcopy "D:\Users\johndoe\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.Modules.Ribbon\bin\Debug\MyProject.Modules.Ribbon.dll" 
>   "D:\Users\johndoe\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\Modules\" /Y" exited with code 9009.    MyProject.Modules.Ribbon

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found my answer: The command had a line break between the source and destination strings. So, Visual Sudio was treating it as two commands. Eliminating the line break solved the problem.

Comment: also spaces in a name "Program Files" vs "ProgramFiles" causes this

Answer (score 34):

I encounted this error on the TeamCity build server. I finally resolved it after checking the build log and found:

> **"'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command."**

I then changed my statement to:

> **C:\Windows\System32\xcopy** "$(ProjectDir)config\Web.config.$(ConfigurationName)" "$(ProjectDir)Web.config" /Y/R

Comment: xcopy worked good for me yesterday, today I had to use %windir%\system32\xcopy

Comment: When I tried configuring the Java, may PATH variable Control Panel\System and Security\System -> Environment variables were modified. I guess that's why xcopy command was not understood. Now it works ! thanks.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.  Xcopy was not on the path for some reason.

Comment: You can add C:\Windows\System32 to your system PATH variable.

Answer (score 32):

Restart Visual Studio. Worked for me

Comment: It worked, but also I needed to clean up the bin folder

Answer (score 11):

This error can occur if your system PATH environment variable has been set incorrectly. The path should contain (at the very least)

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
```

on modern versions of Windows (see https://superuser.com/questions/124239/what-is-the-default-path-environment-variable-setting-on-fresh-install-of-window). I have just found my system PATH had been set to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Bad Vendor\Buggy Program;
```

by an msi installer that obviously has issues.

If you don't know how to edit the PATH via the System Properties dialog, check out this link : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519 - it's basically the same in Windows 7 & 8 as it is in XP.

Finally, it's worth noting that a lot of programs don't notice if you update the PATH while they are running, so closing down and re-opeing programs like Visual Studio or command prompt windows will be required for the repaired path to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

Your `xcopy` command failed for some reason.

I would guess that either the DLL file doesn't exist (eg, the build failed) or the target path doesn't exist.

Run the same command line in a command prompt and see what error it prints.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help.

I gave complete path of xCopy and it worked for me.

```
%windir%\system32\xcopy

%windir%\system32\xCopy "$(ProjectDir)app\ExtjsWS\build\*.*" "$(publishUrl)\app\ExtjsWS\build" /y /i/e</PostBuildEvent>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, this helped my problem than the other accepted answers!!!

Answer (score 1):

Even though its a old post, I found fix which may help some one.

**What not helped me**

```
Restarting visual studio.
Restarting computer
tried few steps as above and few more blogs
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

**What helped me.**

Check the **Environmental Variables** check the PATH, does it has all or nothing or only a part.

since I was having backup of System PATH, I just copy-pasted the variables Under

```
System Variables -> Path.
```

At last, I gave rebuild to the project voila! it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case: i fix it do this:
Add value %SystemRoot%\system32 to Environmental variable's Path variable,and restart my computer,rebuild the solution，it goes fine.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly related to path C\Program files...\some.exe. It should be "C\Program files...\some.exe"

Answer (score 0):

windows defender was blocking access for me, because I get so many of these silly push notifications I was just ignoring it during the build process. Click the notification and allow access for xcopy.
Problem solved