# Build error in Visual C#

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

In Visual C# Express, when I try to `Build Solution`, I get the following message:

> "The command "copy C:\Program Files.....\vaultforms.dll  C:\Documents and Settings\All Users \Application Data......\Vault2012\Extensions\""  exited with code 9009.

(I have only shown part of the paths here but it should be enough to explain the issue)
How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Do you have some pre-build or post-build scrpits?  Can you post the script if you do?

Comment: Step 1: post the part of your Output window that's around the error.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988668/xcopy-exited-with-code-9009

Comment: This may be useful to you:

[Exited with code 9009][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351830/exited-with-code-9009

Answer (score 1):

Check out some other "Exited with Code 9009" errors?

[What does "exited with code 9009" mean during this build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351830/exited-with-code-9009)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908268

Comment: Here is the full text of the error:   The command "copy "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autodesk Vault 2012 SDK\VS9\Csharp\VaultForms\VaultForms\bin\Release\VaultForms.dll" 
"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Autodesk\Vault 2012\Extensions\VaultForms\"" exited with code 9009.
    (I have checked other examples of error 9009 but they don't seem to be relevant).

Comment: Can you confirm that the .dll exists on your hard drive under the first path shown? And if so, that the correct permissions are in place? If those don't fix it, maybe try physically copying it into the project directory and referencing that one instead - somehow the copy command is failing.

Comment: The dll exists under the first path, yes. But interestingly, I don't have a "Documents and Settings" folder at all. (I am on Windows 7). Should this not be pointing to"C:\Users"instead?                      It's acting like a Windows XP installation.

Comment: Ah, that's why it fails! More importantly, why is it trying to copy that .dll there in the first place? Is there a pre- or post-build event doing that? Do you need the .dll copied at all?

Comment: It does it automatically from VC# Express when I press F6 or "Build Solution".  How can I control where it writes to, or prevent it from writing altogether?

Comment: Right-click the project, go to properties - check out Build Events and see if there is a copy command.

Comment: Finally cracked it - he command had a line break between the source and destination strings. So, Visual Sudio was treating it as two commands. Eliminating the line break solved the problem. (As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988668/xcopy-exited-with-code-9009)  - you were right, Almo

Answer (score 0):

Check Path in Environment variable, some basics path information may be missing like visual studio installed path.