# SubWCRev exited with code 9009

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2008, tortoisesvn

> Error 50  The command "SubWCRev "C:\Users\texasman\Desktop\flash\FD\"
>   "C:\Users\texasman\Desktop\flash\FD\FlashDevelop\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs.rev"
>   "C:\Users\texasman\Desktop\flash\FD\FlashDevelop\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs""
>   exited with code 9009.    FlashDevelop

I get that error trying to build flashdevelop's latest trunk. I was interested in using the program for developing some flash for my website. but everything I do I can't build it cause of that error.

I have tried vs 2008 which is the prescribed version and I just tried it with vs 2010.

I am using tortoisesvn to pull it down. and on win 7.

```
 AssemblyInfo.cs.rev - exists in the folder.
 AssemblyInfo.cs     - does not exist in the folder.
```

I have searched all over the place for a solution to this that I can use and\or understand.

It is the first time I have had an issue like this using `svn`, but I must add that I have never used `svn` before actively. I have downloaded programs via svn, but never had any issues.

whats up and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, what i did to fix this particular error is i added the system varibale "%FILE_DEBUG%" to the system environment varibales to the correct path to SubWCRev.exe.

for whatever reason, tortoiseSVN did not add that during install.

so if anyone else is having a similar issue such as this, check that first.

the typical place to check is right click my computer and select properties. on the first tab there will be a button for environment variables. add a new one to the lower list just in case you use multiple accounts. add var name %FILE_DEBUG% and full path to c:\full\path\to\SubWCRev.exe.

thx for the help and i hope this helps others. :)

Comment: I am investigating this issue for a colleague. On my machine, there is no environment variable %FILE_DEBUG%, but subwcrev works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Can see nothing wrong with your command, except (unrelated to problem)

- Uleless Quotation Mars around command and parameters (no spaces - no marks)
- Save subwcrev'ed file inside WC - not best choice (you must don't forget svn:ignore it)

In commom: `SUBWCREV WC-PATH TPL-FILE RES-FILE` is the right pattern, if

- C:\Users\texasman\Desktop\flash\FD\ is Working Copy (best case - clean)
- AssemblyInfo.cs.rev contain SubWCRev keywords

Steps for debug:

1. Run SubWCRev without template file in command prompt: `subwcrev.exe C:\Users\texasman\Desktop\flash\FD\`
2. Run SubWCRev with short and easy template
3. Increase complexity of template to AssemblyInfo.cs.rev

Comment: thx for the response. im gonna give it a try with the level of understanding that i have of what you just said, but please dummy that down a bit, cause i know absolutely nothing about svn. thx.

Comment: C:\Users\texasman\Desktop\flash\FD>subwcrev.exe
'subwcrev.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. got that when i tried first step.

Comment: @texasman1979 - OK, find subwcrev.exe in your system and use full path to fle in command (hint: subwcrev is a part of TortoiseSVN)

Answer (score 1):

Similar error with Visual-Studio 2012. Ran the command manually at the command prompt and it worked.

Fixed the problem by quitting Visual Studio and re-running it.

Comment: Thanks. Worked the same for me in Visual Studio 2015 (exiting completely, not using Restart).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In this case, I think the 9009 is coming from Visual Studio and not SubWCRev.exe. The answer that worked for me was found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1988703/90236. It explains how to add the directory where subwcrev.exe is installed to your %PATH% environment variable.

In my case, I was following the example from http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/embed-svns-revision-into-assemblyinfos-version-number/ and had a pre-build event like:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\SubWCRev.exe" $(ProjectDir). $(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo_template.cs $(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
```

My mistake was I had not properly quoted the path to the Exe, so the space in the path for "Program files" caused the 9009 error. Fixing my quoted path fixed the error.