# Bootstrap.less using dotless compiler exited with code 9009

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, less, dotless, pre-build-event

I'm pulling my hair out with the following error:

> Error 1   The command ""C:\Users\Timothy\Documents\Visual Studio 
>   2012\Projects\QProject\packages\dotless.1.3.1.0\tool\dotless.compiler.exe
>   -m -w"  "C:\Users\Timothy\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\QProject\QProject\Content \less\bootstrap.less"" exited
>   with code 9009.   QProject

I know that code 9009 is related to file not found, but the location of the bootstrap.less and dotless compiler is correct. I've triple checked it.

This is what I entered in the Pre-build Event:

> "$(SolutionDir)packages\dotless.1.3.1.0\tool\dotless.compiler.exe -m
>   -w"  "$(ProjectDir)Content\less\bootstrap.less"

I also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988668/why-does-xcopy-exit-with-code-9009-in-visual-studio-post-build-step) (the solution for this post was: removing the line break in between the command and the arguments) but this did not solve my issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure it out and I forgot to post the answer. So sorry.

So the problem was the argument "-m -w ".

They're not suppose to be in the quotation.

So instead of:

```
"$(SolutionDir)packages\dotless.1.3.1.0\tool\dotless.compiler.exe -m -w" 
"$(ProjectDir)Content\less\bootstrap.less"
```

Use this:

```
"$(SolutionDir)packages\dotless.1.3.1.0\tool\dotless.compiler.exe" -m
"$(ProjectDir)Content\less\bootstrap.less"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I removed the spaces in the path and the problem was gone.

I notice you too have the spaces in the the folder path  to your project solution i.e. [Visual Studio 2012] where you solution resides.

Consider Renaming removing any spaces from the path or alternatively changing the location of your project to the path such that there are no spaces in the folder names.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But any spaces in folder path is okay as long as they are wrapped in quotation marks. I did try your solution just in case if I'm wrong but it did not work.

But I did solve my issue, see the answer that I've just posted.