# i have a xcopy error vs 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The command "
    if not exist "C:\binance projects\Coin trading\CoinTNet-master\CoinTNet\bin\Debug\x86" md "C:\binance projects\Coin trading\CoinTNet-master\CoinTNet\bin\Debug\x86"
    xcopy /s /y "C:\binance projects\Coin trading\CoinTNet-master\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8876.1\NativeBinaries\x86\*.*" "C:\binance projects\Coin trading\CoinTNet-master\CoinTNet\bin\Debug\x86"
    if not exist "C:\binance projects\Coin trading\CoinTNet-master\CoinTNet\bin\Debug\amd64" md "C:\binance projects\Coin trading\CoinTNet-master\CoinTNet\bin\Debug\amd64"
    xcopy /s /y "C:\binance projects\Coin trading\CoinTNet-master\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact.4.0.8876.1\NativeBinaries\amd64\*.*" "C:\binance projects\Coin trading\CoinTNet-master\CoinTNet\bin\Debug\amd64"
" exited with code 9009.    CoinTNet
```

This is my error. I don't know how to solve it.
I'm using Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988668/why-does-xcopy-exit-with-code-9009-in-visual-studio-post-build-step

Comment: The IDE can only produce a "it did not work" diagnostic.  You have to look in the Output window for the specific error message produced by this script.