# the command xcopy exited with code 9009 visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I setup project from git. but when i build solution I got an error "the command xcopy... exited with code 9009. I did not find any solution.
below are the commands by default in Post build event command line:-

xcopy "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(TargetFileName)" "$(SolutionDir)..\Educate\bin\" /s /i /y
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(TargetFileName)" "$(SolutionDir)..\PlayList\bin\" /s /i /y
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(TargetFileName)" "$(SolutionDir)..\EducateFHCRC\FredHutch\FredHutch\bin\" /s /i /y
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(TargetFileName)" "$(SolutionDir)..\EducateFHCRC\FredHutch\FredHutch.Domain\bin\" /s /i /y

This is the full error:-

```
Error       The command "xcopy "D:\Projects\Educate\EmpowerLearn\EducateAssessment\bin\EducateAssessment.dll" "D:\Projects\Educate\EmpowerLearn\EducateAssessment\..\Educate\bin\" /s /i /y
```

xcopy "D:\Projects\Educate\EmpowerLearn\EducateAssessment\bin\EducateAssessment.dll" "D:\Projects\Educate\EmpowerLearn\EducateAssessment..\PlayList\bin\" /s /i /y
xcopy "D:\Projects\Educate\EmpowerLearn\EducateAssessment\bin\EducateAssessment.dll" "D:\Projects\Educate\EmpowerLearn\EducateAssessment..\EducateFHCRC\FredHutch\FredHutch\bin\" /s /i /y
xcopy "D:\Projects\Educate\EmpowerLearn\EducateAssessment\bin\EducateAssessment.dll" "D:\Projects\Educate\EmpowerLearn\EducateAssessment..\EducateFHCRC\FredHutch\FredHutch.Domain\bin\" /s /i /y" exited with code 9009.  EducateAssessment

Comment: What does code 9009 mean?

Comment: I don't know it may be some error code @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 0):

You should try restarting Visual Stutio. Worked for me.

Maybe your path is incorrect, it should be something like this :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Bad Vendor\Buggy Program;
```

Or is just that a DLL file is missing. To see, run the same command line in CMD and see the output. DLL's are easy to download, from here : https://www.dll-files.com/

More info on this thread : [Why does xcopy exit with code 9009 in Visual Studio post-build step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988668/why-does-xcopy-exit-with-code-9009-in-visual-studio-post-build-step)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988668/why-does-xcopy-exit-with-code-9009-in-visual-studio-post-build-step. this worked for me but if I set full path C:\Windows\System32... then when i make pull request i need to change all xcopy path which is difficult for me @apm11

Comment: So it is working now right?

Answer (score 0):

The 'xcopy' executable can't be found. Check your PATH variable for 'C:\Windows\System32\' - if this not exists, add this at the front of PATH.